# SQL insert with function referencing same row

Tags: sql, sqlite

Can I do something like this is SQL?

```
INSERT INTO table (a, b) VALUES ('qwerty', upper(a));
```

I want the result to be a row with `a: qwerty` and `b: QWERTY`. This exact example doesn't work, but can I do it a different way?

Please do not tell me to just calculate it on my own. The above is just a simplified example. The actual use is a very complex function that is implemented as a function in SQL.

If it makes a difference, I am using SQLite.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
 INSERT INTO the_table
 SELECT a, upper(a) FROM
 ( SELECT 'qwerty' a )
```